# Execute stored procedure in directus headless cms

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, graphql, directus

I just find directus headless cms

Looks awesome. It resolve many uses cases for me.

But I am concerned about how to achieve transactions, aggregate functions or complex queries. I understand that maybe is out scope.

If a custom endpoint or graphql allow me execute a stored procedure i will have all my needs achieved.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi finally I find how to use custom endpoints to do plain querys, including stored procedures.

Maybe is possible implement a module for add admin gui option for that, I try work in that, for the moment this is the example for a select:

```
use Directus\Application\Http\Request;
use Directus\Application\Http\Response;

return [
'' => [
    'method' => 'GET',
    'handler' => function (Request $request, Response $response) {

        $container = \Directus\Application\Application::getInstance()->getContainer();
        $dbConnection = $container->get('database');
        $tableGateway = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('directus_users', $dbConnection);

        $query = $tableGateway->getAdapter()->query("select * from productos where 1=1");

        $result = $query->execute();

        if ($result->count() > 0) {
            $returnArr = array();
            while ($result->valid()) {
                $returnArr[] = $result->current();
                $result->next();
            }
            if (count($returnArr) > 0) {
                return $response->withJson([
                    'data' => [
                        $returnArr,
                    ],
                ]);
            }
        }
        return "{}";
    },
],
];
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: is it possible to use this to execute any sprocs? how would I pass in variables? Thanks!